# How can I fix issue with android studio 3.0.1 while creating release signed build

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-studio-3.0

**Getting error:**

```
Error:Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with
classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer
versions or alternative libraries that don’t have the same problem
(for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead),
or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
[DuplicatePlatformClasses]

Error:Error: httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now
provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or
alternative libraries that don’t have the same problem (for example,
for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or
repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
[DuplicatePlatformClasses]
```

Already tried the solution , its not working:

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```

With these changes, not able to receive the http and socket response.Before updating the android studio the build seemed to be fine.

**Build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.0@aar'
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.0"
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'org.mongodb:bson:3.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.embedly:embedly-api:0.1.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.9.0'
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0' // Chrome Tab matching
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0' // GAID matching
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0' // App indexing
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    compile 'ca.barrenechea.header-decor:header-decor:0.2.6'
    compile 'org.solovyev.android.views:linear-layout-manager:0.5@aar'
    compile group: 'ru.noties', name: 'scrollable', version: '1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:7.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'


    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: post your whole gradle file